# Transaction Signature verification failed

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I'm getting a `Signature verification failed` error from nowhere before this it was working 100% fine.

```
const UserStakeAccount = new PublicKey(stakeAccount);

        const { vaultAccount } = await stakeProgram.account.stakePool.fetch(
          stakePoolAccount
        ); const UserStakeAccount = new PublicKey(stakeAccount);

        const [programAuthority, bump_seed] =
          await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
            [Buffer.from(anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode('authority'))],
            stakeProgram.programId
          );
        const { vaultAccount } = await stakeProgram.account.stakePool.fetch(
          stakePoolAccount
        );

 await stakeProgram.rpc.withdraw({
          accounts: {
            userStakeAccount: UserStakeAccount,
            receiverTokenAccount: userTokenAccount,
            vaultAccount: vaultAccount,
            vaultAuthority: programAuthority,
            stakePoolAccount: stakePoolAccount,
            authority: publicKey,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
          },
        });
```

Comment: Kindly provide more context. Full code snippets if any. Otherwise it's difficult to give an helpful answer

Comment: @Ademola I've edit the question

Answer (score 2):

You're not specifying the signature your instruction requires. Any account marked with the `#[account(signer)]` attribute or that is of type `Signer<'info>` needs to sign for your instruction to work.

Anchor can tell from the IDL what signatures you should be passing in and thus throws that error knowing that you haven't passed in the required signature(s).

I can't tell the accounts that need to sign unless I see your on-chain `Accounts` struct, but call the method with this format:

```
await StakeProgram.methods
    .withdraw()
    .accounts({
        //Fill with the needed accounts as done above 
    })
    .signers([])
    .rpc();
```

The signers array argument should be populated so it contains the keypairs of your instructions's signers.

Comment: do I have to provide the signer of the user also?

Comment: Usually no. The connected provider wallet signs every transaction by default in anchor

Comment: I'm not creating any account in this transaction.

Comment: Is the `authority` your anchor provider wallet(provider.publicKey)? It'll only sign your tx by default if that's the case. 

Otherwise if it's a separate account you created with `Keypair.generate()`, you have to explicitly sign by passing the keypair into the array in `.signers([])`.

Comment: after brief debugging I've found that my [PDA](https://explorer.solana.com/address/8PuMAo6NUnMWPootPpTD77K8zMYTQpwyRFtnTRrD8ZyA) is deleted.  how? I have token in it. how can I get my token?

Comment: I took a look at the link and the closed account `8PuMA...` has no tokens.

Comment: but my token account does and the authority of that token account is this. [TOKENS](https://explorer.solana.com/address/8PuMAo6NUnMWPootPpTD77K8zMYTQpwyRFtnTRrD8ZyA/tokens)

Comment: If you still have the keypair of the program it's derived from then you can reinitialize it and transactions it signs for should work as usual

Comment: can you tell me how can I do that?